# Hive query to get all rows where a particular column value lies in a particular precentile

Tags: hive

I am trying to filter my rows in hive table named `id_counts` based on percentile values. 
Lets considers the following table.

```
+------+----------+
|  id  | quantity |
+------+----------+
| a01  |      234 |
| a02  |      345 |
| a03  |       23 |
+------+----------+
```

now lets say I want to get the rows which have quantity in the 90th percentile then what query should i give.
I tried the following:

```
select * from id_counts having quantity>=  percentile(quantity, 0.9);
```

But it gives the error:
`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:54 Expression not in GROUP BY key '0.9'`

Update:
I am able to resolve this using the following query but is there a simpler method?

```
select * from id_count a cross join
    (select percentile(quantity, 0.9) as top_ones
     from id_count) aa
where a.quantity >= aa.top_ones;
```

A simpler query would be appreciated. Is it possible that no join is required?

Comment: I have no idea about _hive_, but from pure SQL, why do you use _HAVING_ instead of simply _WHERE_?